# Exclude Properties in Azure CLI Output's JSON

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, jmespath

I'm trying to exclude a few properties from Azure's CLI Output. I know I can use `--query` to filter through the output using its JMESPath. But I want to exclude just one of them, so it doesn't make sense to select all the other using `--query`.

Is there a way to do this? I'm looking for something similar to what PowerShell can do:

```
Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty
```

The following example illustrates one particular case.

Sample Command: `az ad group list -o json`

Output:

```
[
 {
    "deletionTimestamp": null,
    "description": "app_description",
    "dirSyncEnabled": null,
    "displayName": "name",
    "lastDirSyncTime": null,
    "mail": "sample@domain.com",
    "mailEnabled": true,
    "mailNickname": "sampleMail",
    "objectId": "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxx",
    "objectType": null,
    "onPremisesDomainName": null,
    "onPremisesNetBiosName": null,
    "onPremisesSamAccountName": null,
    "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
    "provisioningErrors": [],
    "proxyAddresses": [],
    "securityEnabled": false
  }
]
```

Expected Output: Same as above, but without the `description` and `objectId` properties.

Comment: Can you provide the command you're trying and also your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

JMESPath doesn't support removing properties/keys as of today. This ask has been open for a while now: [Ability to set and delete based on a jmespath #121](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py/issues/121)

As mentioned in the linked GitHub issue, one workaround would be to pipe the output (`$json`) to `jq`:

```
echo $json | jq 'del(.[0].objectId, .[0].description)'
```

that would produce the following output excluding `objectId` and `description`:

```
[
  {
    "deletionTimestamp": null,
    "dirSyncEnabled": null,
    "displayName": "name",
    "lastDirSyncTime": null,
    "mail": "sample@domain.com",
    "mailEnabled": true,
    "mailNickname": "sampleMail",
    "objectType": null,
    "onPremisesDomainName": null,
    "onPremisesNetBiosName": null,
    "onPremisesSamAccountName": null,
    "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
    "provisioningErrors": [],
    "proxyAddresses": [],
    "securityEnabled": false
  }
]
```